# How to delete data from mysql database with angularjs $http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code

```
        $scope.Delete = function(customer ){

        $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'rest/customers',
        data: {customers:customer.custId},

        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.customers.splice($scope.customers.indexOf(customer), 1);
        }); 
    }
```

If I call this function it only deletes the data from the front-end. The data is not getting deleted from mysql table. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: all i can say is...u need to write your sql to deleted data uising the passed customer id in that particular table on  your backend

Comment: Can you show you backend code?

Comment: Not possible actually, tonnes of codes and pages are their in java and hibernate. You can suggest any possible way for this.Trying to use google's postman collection to call the delete api

Comment: And how can we help without knowing what the endpoint called from your angular code does?!

Comment: I wish for help but their isn't any ways to share the project as you asked. Looking forward for any solution from you.

Comment: if the backend is truly RESTful, it should be something like `$http.delete('rest/customers/' + customer.custId).then(...`

Answer (score 1):

```
//try like this..sure it will work
$http.delete('your url' + id).then(function(result){
   if(result.data){
     //your handle code
   }
}, function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: No, not working. I am using eclipse, so $http.delete is showing error

Comment: Please refer http://tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-http-delete-method-http-delete-example-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not efficient to test api with front end code, you need to set up a [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) test to separate your concern, get it working in postman first.

After postman test, you can use $http.delete, sample link is [here](http://techfunda.com/howto/576/http-delete-server-request)